# HDMI to monitor with no speakers - How to get audio?

Tags: audio, hdmi, speakers, chromecast

I have this spare monitor lying around:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00F6390EI?redirect=true&ref_=s9_im_co_g147_i4

I was thinking of using it to stream videos on. It has no 3.5mm jack or built in speakers. I will be able to use my laptop speakers but I'd prefer to get USB speakers and plug them into the monitor itself.

I'm wondering if the audio will go from my laptop through HDMI to the monitor and then play through the USB speakers?

Ideally I'd like to get a chromecast so I'd have no connections with my laptop and possibly stream from my phone too.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but the P2014H does not have an HDMI input. It has a DVI input, and you can get a cheap adapter from HDMI to DVI, and that works fine for video. But DVI inputs almost never support audio.

In addition the USB functionality in that monitor is nothing but a USB 2.0 hub with an input and four outputs. The only way you would be able to run USB speakers from it is if you have a USB cable from your PC to the monitor. They will just show up in your computer as USB speakers. Your video card and the DVI cable won't be involved.

A Chromecast plugged into the monitor... it's possible that it could find USB speakers that were plugged into the monitor hub's USB outputs. I don't know. But from what I know of the Chromecast, I doubt it - the only thing the Chromecast uses the USB for is power.